# Persian URL issue in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs for my application and found this issue on google chrome, the problem is I have this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/#/fa/episode/1315019/برنامه-خوب
```

but when I click on this links it shows:

```
http://127.0.0.1/#/fa/episode/1315019/%D9%82%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1
```

I'm using **$routeProvider**  for my routing, it works fine in firefox but I have issue with that in google chrome.

why is that and how should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant fix this "problem" but it actually should not be a problem at all.

URLs can only contain these characters:

> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>       a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - _ . ~
>       ! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]

All other characters, like `<`, `§` and the characters contained in `برنامه-خوب` will get encoded.

Encoding means, that they get replaced by a combination of valid characters, in your case `برنامه-خوب` gets replaced by `%D9%82%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1` which is no issue, its the way how an URL works, you can not change it.